# Qt for android build failure (install_target error 129)

Tags: android, c++, windows, qt

I'm tring to build the Qt Quick Demo - Calqlatr bundled with Qt for an android device w/ armeabi-v7 but i get a

```
[install_target] Error 129
```

looking at the detailed output it shows

```
[...]
14:48:09: The process "C:\Qtwdroid\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
14:48:09: Starting: "C:\Qtwdroid\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" "INSTALL_ROOT=C:/Qtwdroid/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Release/android-build" install
      0 [main] sh 2744 sync_with_child: child 6128(0x1A8) died before initialization with status code 0xC0000142
     26 [main] sh 2744 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
/usr/bin/sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Makefile:588: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_target] Error 129
14:48:11: The process "C:\Qtwdroid\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project calqlatr (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.0))
When executing step "Copy application data"
14:48:11: Elapsed time: 00:11.
```

i did followed these steps on the Qt Docs http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html the only difference is that i have jdk 1.8-102

The makefile is avaible in pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/rYyisieu

i did not find this error on the internet, i'm really lost

im new to the subject,
Thanks.

Comment: Target android is 5.1.1 API 22 (if this helps in any way)